# Does FileMode.Append read the entire file?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have read the documentation for AppendText and FileMode.Append, which says it seeks to the end of the filestream.  What is not clear is whether or not this is more efficient than other techniques that read to the end of the file.  Does a seek cause the entire file to be read?

I just want to get a better understanding of this so I understand the performance implications when dealing with extremely large files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a seek cause the entire file to be read?

No. It just uses the file system seek operation to move the logical cursor to the end of the file. I'd expect it to usually be an O(1) operation, but that would depend on the file system implementation. For example, the file system may contain a linked list of blocks or something like that - in which case it could be an O(n) operation, but still pretty quick; it wouldn't need to read every byte of the file.